# How to efficiently check different date formats when converting month to number

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, conditional-statements, try-except

I'm trying to convert a given month to a month number in integer format. There are three valid formats that I want to try to convert. A month number that's given as a string (input function returns a string), a month abbreviation, and a full month name.

While my function works as intended I feel like it's not that well written, despite my attempts to make it as clean as possible. In particular, I'm not happy that I have an except statement that just passes. Handling both a string conversion to an integer AND checking to see if the string is a valid month to convert to an integer was a tough task.

I tried to change the order of the try-excepts, removing the string-to-int to make it's on try-except block without going straight into the date formatting in the exception but that's about it. The function below is the best attempt I've had. I couldn't think of anything else except maybe create helper functions?

## Code

```
def get_start_month_updated():
    date_formats = ['%b', '%B']
    while True:
        month = input("What is the starting month?")
        try:
            month_num = int(month)
            if 1 <= month_num <= 12:
                return month_num
        except ValueError:
            for date_format in date_formats:
                try:
                    month_num = strptime(month, date_format).tm_mon
                    return month_num
                except ValueError:
                    pass
            else:
                print("You must enter a valid month")
        else:
            print("You must enter a valid month")
```

My results are correct and the function works as intended, but I feel like the code is messy and there is a better way to do this without getting really convoluted.

Comment: `while True` is wrong approach for the vast majority of cases, including yours. Yes, helper function: this main function should consist solely of input line and `return get_int_month(month)`.

Comment: How do I prompt the user for the correct value without a ```While True``` loop? If the input is not valid, the user should be asked for a new input until a correct one is given

Comment: Ok then, three lines: `value = get_int_month(month); return value if value else get_start_month_updated()`

Comment: So use recursion instead? What's the benefit of using recursion over a while loop in this case? I thought using While loops are fine as long as you make sure you aren't stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: First of all, everything is fine: pythonic is utopia. I just don't like `while True` out of gui's main loop. It's not really a recursion, it's a call to a mandatory task that has not been finished yet.

Comment: Ah okay! Just for a bit of context, this particular block of code isn't in the main loop, it's just to get this particular input out of many. If you don't mind me asking, why do you prefer not using a ```while True loop``` as opposed a function call? 

I'm just wondering since in your first comment you stated "```while True``` is wrong approach for the vast majority of cases, including yours." Just wondering the rational.

Comment: Afaic `while True` should be used only for a GUI main loop, as that's reasonable approach for listening to finite, but unpredictable, number of events. You're listening/expecting a sole event and that's the reason why I think an infinite loop should be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should create a *parse_month* function for better testing.
This *parse_month* function can have several internal parsers, one for each format: "int", datetime with "%b", datetime with "%B". This is implementation detail.

One way to do that could be:

```py
import datetime
import functools


def parse_month(value):
    def from_int(v):
        month_num = int(v)
        if 1 <= month_num <= 12:
            return month_num
        raise ValueError(v)

    def from_month_fmt(fmt, v):
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(v, fmt).month

    parsers = (
        from_int,
        functools.partial(from_month_fmt, "%b"),
        functools.partial(from_month_fmt, "%B"),
    )
    for parser in parsers:
        try:
            return parser(value)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    else:
        raise ValueError(value)
```

Then, you can use this function to prompt the user:

```py
def get_start_month_updated():
    while True:
        month = input("What is the starting month?")
        try:
            month_num = parse_month(month)
        except ValueError:
            print("You must enter a valid month")
        else:
            return month_num
```

If you don't want to reinvent the wheel, [Arrow](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is your friend:

```py
import arrow

def parse_month(value):
    formats = (
        "MMMM",
        "MMM",
        "MM",
        "M"
    )
    for fmt in formats:
        try:
            return arrow.get(value, fmt).month
        except arrow.parser.ParserError:
            pass
    else:
        raise ValueError(value)
```

Comment: Is there no way to check for a valid conversion without having ```except ValueError: pass```? Or is this one of those cases that it's acceptable because you raise the value later if no value is valid. I Thought it was generally bad form to have a try-except statement where the exception is handled with just pass.

Comment: Both suggestions work! I especially really like the arrow module! Thanks for showing me that, I'm definitely going to read into it more, seems very useful

Comment: Using `except ValueError: pass` is not bad, it's the "EAFP" (Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission) principal. Instead of that, you can use a RegEx to match the input value and then a parser to convert the value. But, here, this is not appropriate.